# API VK отдает пустой ответ после нескольких выполнений цикла

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пишу приложение которое отбирает нужных мне людей. Использую метод `users.search`. Запросы выполняются в цикле, так как иногда параметры меняются. И вот после нескольких циклов все последующие ответы приходят пустые. С чем это связано? Как это можно обойти?

Но если применять access_token другого аккаунта, он начнет выдавать ответы, но опять же, после нескольких циклов ответы пустые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Dodik ага, понял. а когда возобновиться доступ моему ключу?

Comment: Покажите, какие параметры Вы передаёте в `users.search`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов `?count=1000&fields=contacts,city,bdate&country=3&sex='.$sex.'&status='.$status.'&age_from='.$age_from.'&age_to='.$age_to.'&birth_day='.$birth_day.'&has_photo=1&v=5.92&access_token=`

Comment: >Иногда параметры меняются. А Вы уверены, что в цикле не попадаются такие параметры, по которым поиск никого не находит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в том что у ВК есть лимит на кол-во запросов каждого метода, как в секунду так и в сутки, и вот когда лимит превышен - приходит пустой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Это тоже самое, что и ошибка 429 (Too Many Requests), из-за нее вы и получаете пустой ответ.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).